# Built wsdl does not match wsdl.xml configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, wsdl

I'm working on a site that was recently migrated to a new server. The previous dev mentioned that the Magento API worked for SOAP v2, but I can't verify that is the case so I'm not sure if this issue is specific to my environment. I'm on Magento 1.9.2.4. The error I'm getting when I attempt to parse the wsdl in the client is the following:

```
WSDLException (at /definitions/binding/operation[7]/operation):
faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered illegal extension element 
'{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}operation' in the context of a 
'javax.wsdl.BindingOperation'. Extension elements must be in a namespace 
other than WSDL's
```

The error is pointing to this location in the wsdl:

```
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Magento" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
 ...
<binding name="Binding" type="typens:PortType">
...
<operation name="storeList">
    <operation soapAction="urn:Action"/>
        <input>
             <body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </input>
        <output>
             <body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
```

The `operation` element that is a child of `operation` should have the `soap` namespace. All `operation` elements after this one in this wsdl are also missing the correct namespace. If I look at the wsdl.xml defining this operation, it looks correct as far as I can tell. The following is defined in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/wsdl.xml.

```
<operation name="storeList">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
```

I've reviewed the other wsdl.xml files that exist in my install to see if it's being overridden anywhere, but I don't believe it is. I've cleared the cache in both my client and magento install. I've also tried renaming some of the wsdl.xml files to see if I could tell if one of them was introducing the error, but no luck so far. Any ideas on what could be causing this?